# How to update the version of my app without deleting client database using advanced installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, advanced-installer

I have an application on a client machine and I have to fix some bugs. When I'm trying to update using the advanced installer my app loses all of localdb data on the client (the update replaces the database file).

I want to know how to make my update version project replace all files except localdb files.

My files:
[image]

Comment: This seems like a poor design to me. As a developer and an application user, I would expect that my data would remain untouched when performing an application update. If the structure ever needs to be changed that would be a recoverable migration either as a standalone upgrade or as a part of a specific release of your application. That said, I would check for an existing copy of the database and only deploy it if it does not exist.

Comment: yeah what I said that I have to know how to let files without deleting when I update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is a [Do not overwrite existing file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/file-operations-tab.html) option available in Files and Folders view for the related file. You can try to use it and this should work.